# Any Issue With Revoking Certificate Regularly

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, iphone-developer-program, certificate-revocation

**Is there any issue, if I revoke my development certificate regularly (10 times / month) ?**

Let consider I'm developing 3 application using different systems with **1 development certificate and 3 provisioning profiles**. Regularly I'm adding new devices to all our provisional profiles .

When installing  provisioning profile in other 2 machines, **Xcode Organizer** shows an warning as "**A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain** " . So i just revoked  my earlier certificate and generated new certificate request from the same machine keychain. After downloaded the new certificate, all things seems to be ok.

However other machines **Xcode organizers** will display the same warning when try to modify and download the provisioning profiles. So always I will fix the issue this way (revoking & regenerating new one).

So I would like to know, is there any issue, if I revoke my development certificate regularly (like account ban/block etc)?

Comment: There's a problem with the approach to problem-solving.

Comment: Your problem will be the shouting and abuse of your coworkers who get angry when they have to do this all the time.

Comment: @borrrden: lol.. u r correct. now i got it from answer.. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need to revoke your certificate every time.
On the system where the development certificate is installed, go to Key Chain Access and select the both certificate and key, right click to get the option to export, and then export as a file to your desktop. Now send that .p12 file to *another* Mac where you can double click that .p12 file to have it install in in that system's Key Chain Access. You install the certificates in just the same way, and once you have done that it will not show that message.

Comment: An even easier way is to go to Organizer -> Devices, click the profile under "Teams" and then hit "Export" at the bottom.

Comment: Txtspk2english filter applied