# ios provisioning portal certificate can't be install...?

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, private-key, ios-provisioning

I have an iphone application which was created by other and now I'm on the work. Provisioning portal of client already have Development and Distribution certificate. Now I want to install that certificate and work on that application, so I download that certificate and install(just double click), so it showing me in my "keychain access" but I think they are not install properly because of no private key. Can anyone help me what is the process to work on this...!?!

Comment: There should be some problem with generating CSR through KeyChain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to private key for the certificate, which is in the keychain of the mac that requested the certificates.

if you can't get the private key you will need to create a new certificate.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge "rckoenes", Actually application version 1.0 is live, so I think I can't create new certificate from my mac and upload there. In that way the current application is attached with that certificate will stop working. As you say first that "You need to private key for the certificate, which is in the keychain of the mac that requested the certificates.". So can you give me proper steps how client can generate that private key from that mac from which certificate was requested.

Comment: No thats no problem, you can retract the current certifcates and create new once. Nothing will happen to the application in the appstore.

Comment: you mean to say I just revoke the certificate form provisioning portal and create new one. Are you sure that will not affect the current application on app store as well as when I upload the second version through my mac it will uploaded there properly...!?!

Comment: yes I'm sure, I've done it before and the certificates are only valid for 1 year then you are forced to create new once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask the client to send you the private key. He can export from his keychain the private key as .p12 file.

Comment: Actually my client is not familiar with all this stuff. Can you please send me proper step how they can do this for generating .p12 file.

Comment: Did you tried to find out how to export a private key from keychain?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a issue with creation of certificate.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q--ZpEsoHUQ)  will help you.

**or follow the below steps**

Click on the Keychain Access menu-->CertificateAssistance -->Request a certificate from Certificate Authority.

A new window will appear with the Emailaddress,common name etc.. sections.

Type in the email address you used for your appledeveloper certificate in the ‘user email address’ field.

Use any one name as Common Name.

Click ‘Saved to disk’ button.

create certificate from developer portal.

Comment: Thank you very much "Ramshad". But actually this thing works when there is no certificate uploaded on provisioning portal. Actually I have certificate on provisioning portal uploaded by client and now I want to install that certificate to my mac.

Comment: oh.. so you can checkout my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855698/any-issue-with-revoking-certificate-regularly

Comment: go for client machine key chain access and select the both certificate and key,right click u will get a export,then export to desktop .now u send that p12 file to ur mac,now u double click that p12 file,then in key chain access u will get that files,now u install u r certificates ,now it doesn't show that message

Comment: Thanks a lot I think this will help me a lot...!?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask them for provide certificate.p12 file from previous dev or whoever created the certificate signing request to create new certificate.

He can just import the certificate.p12 file form keychain access.